# How to make discord.py bot send to the server it's called in?

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

had a question regarding discord.py.
I run two separate servers that my bot is on, my test server and my main server.
The problem is when I send a message in the test server, the bot then sends its message to the main server, and never sends it back to the server the command is being called in (only in functions).

For example:

```
 if message.content == '!Hello':
 await message.channel.send('Hello there!')
```

If I type the above in the test server, my bot will respond with "Hello there!" in the test server like it should. However, if I tried putting this code in a function and called it:

```
if message.content == "!Hello":
    await hellomessage()

async def hellomessage():
    channel = client.get_channel('Channel ID Here')
    await channel.send('Hello there!')
```

The channel ID is obviously set to a specific server. So say I have ID '1234' as my main server and ID '1111' as my test server, regardless whether I call it in my test server or main server, that message is going to send to the main server because the ID is no different. My question is how do I make sure the "channel" attribute changes depending on the server it was called in. I want it so if I say !Hello in my test server, it doesn't send to the main server and only the test server.

Seems like a very trivial answer but I'm just struggling to find it, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check what guild a message has been sent from using the `.guild` attribute of a message.

Example:

```
# You can also have a separate coroutine for your main server
async def hello_test_message():
    test_guild_channel = client.get_channel(ID_HERE)
    await test_guild_channel.send("Hello there!")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if client.user == message.author:
        return

    if message.guild.id == TEST_GUILD_ID_HERE:
        if message.content.lower() == "!hello":  # .lower() for case insensitivity
            await hello_test_message()
    # Another condition for your main server + calling the other coroutine
```

This being said, I'm assuming that you're not hard-coding values in values for every possible channel etc. and if that is the case, and you just want the bot to respond in the original message's channel, you can use `message.channel.send(...`.

The current method of doing things will result in quite a bit of duplicate code.

I'd also recommend having a look into the commands extension of discord instead of using `on_message` events for them.

---

### References:

- [Bot example using command decorators](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/basic_bot.py)
- [`Message.guild`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.guild)
- [`Guild.id`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.id)
- [`commands.command()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Command)
- [`Message.channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.channel)
- [`TextChannel.send()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.send)
- [`Messageable.send()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.Messageable.send) - [Anything that inherits from `abc.Messageable`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.Messageable) is able to have a message sent to it! So this includes stuff like users, text channels, [context](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context) etc.
- [`commands.Context`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context) - You'll use this a lot when dealing with commands!

Comment: I really appreciate the references for looking into coding more, you can probably tell I'm really new at this.

As for the fix? I changed everything to use message.channel.send(stuff()) instead, and that made it work much better than before!

Comment: @jtnoble worries, I'm glad you found it useful! I'll add in a few more links that may be useful in that case :)